# Getting a path between two nodes and using it to match between two other types of node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I know there are two types of nodes say `(:RefNodeType1)` and `(:RefNodeType2)`. Both will have single instances in the given graph. Then I know there are another two types of nodes `(:TargetNodeType1)` and `(:TargetNodeType2)` with multiple instances of each of them.

I want to know all instances of `(:TargetNodeType1)` and `(:TargetNodeType2)` that have same path between them as the path between `(:RefNodeType1)` and `(:RefNodeType2)`. While saying "same path", I mean to say relationship and node labels on both the paths should be same and should occur in same sequence.

Pseudo cypher may look something like this

```
MATCH path = (:RefNodeType1)-<path-description>-(RefNodeType2)   //<path-description> can be anything, may include variable length relationship e.g. [:XYZ*1..]
WITH path
MATCH (a:TargetNodeType1)-<path>-(b:TargetNodeType2)
RETURN a,b
```

But I dont know how can I specify `<path>`, that is if the path contained in the variable `path` also exists between `TargetNodeType1` and `TargetNodeType2`. I dont know whether such query is possible or not. But still, how can I do this? Also what could be better approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

Let's create an example graph:

```
CREATE 
  (rn1:RefNodeType1 {name: "rn1"}),
  (rn2:RefNodeType2 {name: "rn2"}),
  (tn1:TargetNodeType1 {name: "tn1"}),
  (tn2:TargetNodeType2 {name: "tn2"}),
  (i1:IntermediateNodeType {name: "i1"}),
  (i2:IntermediateNodeType {name: "i2"}),
  (rn1)-[:REL]->(i1)-[:REL]->(rn2),
  (tn1)-[:REL]->(i2)-[:REL]->(tn2)
```

[image]

First, get the node labels along a certain path. We first use the [`nodes()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#functions-nodes) function to extract the nodes of the path. To get the intermediate nodes, we drop the first and the last node, using the `[1..length(nodes)-1]` range (note that the upper limit is [non-inclusive](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#_lists_in_general), e.g. `RETURN ['a', 'b', 'c'][1..2]` return `['b']`). We [`UNWIND`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-unwind) the intermediate nodes so that we can invoke the [`labels()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#functions-labels) method on each of them, and [`collect`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#aggregation-collect) the results to a list.

```
MATCH path = (:RefNodeType1)-[r*]->(:RefNodeType2)
WITH nodes(path) AS nodes
WITH nodes[1..length(nodes)-1] AS refIntermediateNodes
UNWIND refIntermediateNodes AS refIntermediateNode
WITH collect(labels(refIntermediateNode)) AS refIntermediateNodeLabels
RETURN *
```

This results in:

```
╒═════════════════════════╕
│refIntermediateNodeLabels│
╞═════════════════════════╡
│[[IntermediateNodeType]] │
└─────────────────────────┘
```

We apply this to both the `RefNodeType`s and the `TargetNodeType`s.

```
// (1)
MATCH path = (:RefNodeType1)-[r*]->(:RefNodeType2)
WITH nodes(path) AS nodes
WITH nodes[1..length(nodes)-1] AS refIntermediateNodes
UNWIND refIntermediateNodes AS refIntermediateNode
WITH collect(labels(refIntermediateNode)) AS refIntermediateNodeLabels
// (2)
MATCH path = (t1:TargetNodeType1)-[r*]->(t2:TargetNodeType2)
WITH t1, t2, refIntermediateNodeLabels, nodes(path) AS nodes
WITH t1, t2, refIntermediateNodeLabels, nodes[1..length(nodes)-1] AS targetIntermediateNodes
UNWIND targetIntermediateNodes AS targetIntermediateNode
WITH t1, t2, refIntermediateNodeLabels, collect(labels(targetIntermediateNode)) AS targetIntermediateNodeLabels
WHERE refIntermediateNodeLabels = targetIntermediateNodeLabels
RETURN t1, t2
```

Note that in the second `MATCH` (2), we need to pass the `refIntermediateNodeLabels` for each `WITH` clause (as `WITH` [chains the queries](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-with)).

The result is:

```
╒═══════════╤═══════════╕
│t1         │t2         │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│{name: tn1}│{name: tn2}│
└───────────┴───────────┘
```

And, of course we have to do this for relationships as well - the main differences are that 1) we do not have to drop the first and the last one 2) we have to use `type()` instead of `labels()`.

So, to get the relationships along a path:

```
MATCH path = (:RefNodeType1)-[r*]->(:RefNodeType2)
WITH relationships(path) AS refRelationships
UNWIND refRelationships AS refRelationship
WITH collect(type(refRelationship)) AS refRelationshipLabels
RETURN *
```

This results is:

```
╒═════════════════════╕
│refRelationshipLabels│
╞═════════════════════╡
│[REL_A, REL_B]       │
└─────────────────────┘
```

So let's add this all together so we get this nice & simple query:

```
// (1)
MATCH path = (:RefNodeType1)-[r*]->(:RefNodeType2)
WITH nodes(path) AS nodes, relationships(path) AS refRelationships
WITH nodes[1..length(nodes)-1] AS refNodes, refRelationships
UNWIND refNodes AS refNode
WITH refNodes, collect(labels(refNode)) AS refNodeLabels, refRelationships
UNWIND refRelationships AS refRelationship
WITH refNodeLabels, collect(type(refRelationship)) AS refRelationshipLabels
// (2)
MATCH path = (t1:TargetNodeType1)-[r*]->(t2:TargetNodeType2)
WITH t1, t2, refNodeLabels, refRelationshipLabels, nodes(path) AS nodes, relationships(path) AS targetIntermediateRelationships
WITH t1, t2, refNodeLabels, refRelationshipLabels, nodes[1..length(nodes)-1] AS targetIntermediateNodes, targetIntermediateRelationships
UNWIND targetIntermediateNodes AS targetIntermediateNode
WITH t1, t2, refNodeLabels, refRelationshipLabels, collect(labels(targetIntermediateNode)) AS targetIntermediateNodeLabels, targetIntermediateRelationships
UNWIND targetIntermediateRelationships AS targetIntermediateRelationship
WITH t1, t2, refNodeLabels, refRelationshipLabels, targetIntermediateNodeLabels, collect(type(targetIntermediateRelationship)) AS targetIntermediateRelationshipLabels
WHERE refNodeLabels = targetIntermediateNodeLabels
  AND refRelationshipLabels = targetIntermediateRelationshipLabels
RETURN t1, t2
```

**Limitations:** I am not sure this will work for multiple node labels - but it seems they are return in the same order:

```
CREATE (:A:B), (:B:A)

MATCH (n:A)
RETURN labels(n)

╒═════════╕
│labels(n)│
╞═════════╡
│[A, B]   │
├─────────┤
│[A, B]   │
└─────────┘
```